# Support and display different video formats in IE and Firefox browser

Tags: html, html5-video

We have a need to support rendering of the following type of videos using a common code, based on the URL of the video. We need to support IE 6, IE 8 and Firefox 3.0.4 browsers for following file types (videos).

Can you suggest if we can provide a common HTML tags or set of common HTML tags for supporting all these video types based on the URL? Are all these file extensions supported in Firefox and IE?

asx, asf, ram, mpeg, mpg, mpe, qt, mov, avi, movie, wmv, smil, mp4, mxf, gxf, flv, 3gp, f4v, mj2, omf, dv, vob

Thanks.

Comment: After I spent some more time on Internet, I think the best approach to be able to have a video player web page to support all the above different formats of video is to convert all the videos to a common video format (may be FLV) and then render the converted video. Does anyone have a better suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

Not all of those video formats will be supported on all platforms - it depends on what browser is being used, and which codecs have been installed.

An ideal solution would be [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody). It is a simple fallback technique that uses Flash where browsers don't support HTML5 video (thus, IE6/7/8). It still won't support every format in your list (You may need server-side transcoding for that), but will cover all the browsers you require.

Comment: Thanks for the information. From what I see with Video for Everybody, we need to provide three to four different formats of the same video for multiple browsers. Our requirement is that we would not know the type of video until we start requesting a video and render. We are looking for an application that renders any videos from the above list, and provide appropriate HTML (if required) to render that video. The need is to support IE 6, IE 8 and Firefox 3. Is there a link that provides me information what HTML is required for each video type, and what browsers support those video types?

Comment: the diveintohtml5.org site has some useful information - http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html#what-works - but yes, it's only really Vorbis/H.264/WebM. I'm not sure about the other formats, it's not something I've tried. HTML5 video probably won't meet your requirements, if that's the case.